# AS3 - TypeError: Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, exception, nullreferenceexception, typeerror

I'm trying to create a system that puts each block in a block Array which I can use to easily add blocks to the stage via XML, however I'm getting

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

When it initializes the 'blockStone'.

Here's my main Block class, each block is initialized here.

```
package com.snakybo.platformengine.block {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Block extends MovieClip {
        public static var blockList:Array = [];

        public static const blockStone:Block = (new BlockStone(0));

        public var blockID:int;

        private var mc:MovieClip;

        public function Block(blockID:int, mc:MovieClip) {
            if (blockList[blockID] != null) {
                throw new Error("Slot " + blockID + " is already occupied by " + blockList[blockID] + " when adding " + this);
            } else {
                blockList[blockID] = this;

                this.blockID = blockID;
                this.mc = mc;

                mc.x = 100;
                mc.y = 100;

                addChild(mc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the BlockStone class:

```
package com.snakybo.platformengine.block {

    public class BlockStone extends Block {
        public function BlockStone(blockID:int) {
            super(blockID, new stone());
        }
    }
}
```

FlashDevelop refers to this line when it errors:

```
public class BlockStone extends Block {
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at global$init()[C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Extra\Code\Actionscript\PlatformEngine\src\com\snakybo\platformengine\block\BlockStone.as:3]
    at com.snakybo.platformengine.block::Block$cinit()
    at global$init()[C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Extra\Code\Actionscript\PlatformEngine\src\com\snakybo\platformengine\block\Block.as:5]
    at com.snakybo.platformengine::Game()[C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Extra\Code\Actionscript\PlatformEngine\src\com\snakybo\platformengine\Game.as:13]
    at com.snakybo.platformengine::Main/init()[C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Extra\Code\Actionscript\PlatformEngine\src\com\snakybo\platformengine\Main.as:20]
    at com.snakybo.platformengine::Main()[C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Extra\Code\Actionscript\PlatformEngine\src\com\snakybo\platformengine\Main.as:11]
```

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with AS3, since this method works in Java. I'm open to suggestions on better ways to do this in AS3 using block ID's defined in an XML file.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: what line is BlockStone.as:4

Comment: That's `public class BlockStone extends Block {`, I removed the `/** @author */`. I'll edit it

Comment: Lets verify something.  comment out super(blockID, new stone()); and put in trace( new stone())

Comment: It works, '[object stone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're instantiating a new Blockstone before you get through the Block constructor.  Try simply declaring the public static const blockStone:Block; without setting a value to it first, and then set it in Block's constructor.

Comment: I can't define constants in the constructor, and if I remove the const and define it in the constructor it doesn't create/initialize the blockStone when I call it using 'Block.blockList[0]' leaving it undefined.

Comment: Right.  It's been a while since I've done AS3. I think I see the issue.  You've got Block.blockstone set as a const.  If you drop the const attribute, it should be easy to set it.  I hope that helps.  I don't have Flash open in front of me.

Comment: ...oh, it helps if I read your comment more carefully.  Try ditching the const, and instantiating Block, then set Blockstone.  You've got to get through the constructor first because Blockstone is an instance of Block. It's kind of odd.  Do you have many instances of Block on the stage?

Comment: But i'm not running the Block constructor manually, it creates the BlockStone at runtime cause it's static, so if I do `public static blockStone:Block;` and in the constructor `blockStone = new BlockStone(0);` it's never initialized cause Block isn't instantiated anywhere. I'm just accessing it staticly.

Comment: Okay, this code should be all you'll need. In the main class do try something like `trace(Block.blockList[0]);`, and you'll need a `stone` movieclip.

Comment: I think you might be missing an import statement for Blockstone in the Block class?

Comment: Block and BlockStone are in the same package, so no import needed.

Comment: I've never compiled in FlashDevelop so I can't speak to how it would reference classes, but in Flash itself, despite the fact that it's in the same package, I'd still include an import statement for it. I suspect the reason you're getting the null object reference error is because it can't reference that class.